# How to add a share option in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

I'm developing an iPhone app where I want users to be able to share content from anywhere on their phone to our service. Basically the same way as you can share a website link to Twitter or Facebook.

[image]

So the user for example would be in Safari (or other), is on an interesting website. I want him to be able to select in the share options and a popup appears with the link in a text box where the user can add more text content then send it to my system.

I have no idea where to start. Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is no duplicate. the question is not about a custom UIActivity… the question is about interapp sharing...

Answer (score 3):

Good starting point to achieve what you want

http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Answer (score 2):

> I want users to be able to share content from anywhere on their phone to our service

If you mean you would like to extend the default set of shareable services, you cannot do that, only Apple can.

What you could do is publish a service through an app of yours, so that "compatible" apps can call that service and share their content with your service through your app. This is usually attained by defining a custom URL scheme and a handler for that scheme in your app.

You can have a look at [this project](http://www.handleopenurl.com) for some more information and also look at other apps that are doing the same as you would like.